# Двойной (множественный) запрос к grafana api

Tags: grafana

Имею:

- grafana;
- источник данных prometheus, собирает некую метрику xxx.

Могу вывести двойной график в графане, используя два запроса sum(xxx) и count(xxx).
Бекенд моего приложения обращается к granfana api и получает данные, выполняя запрос:

```
[grafanaUrl]/api/datasources/proxy/uid/[thanosUid]/api/v1/query?query=sum(xxx)
```

Возможно ли послать несколько promQL запросов одним get запросом к grafana api и получить несколько результатов в одном JSON?